# Hide and show custom Field based on the Order Status

Tags: acumatica

Client has an Customised field called “Approval Type” on the Purchase Order Entry screen (screenshot attached). By Default this field is available when user creates an Order.

We are implementing the Approval Workflow for this client. The client wants that when a new PO is created, this field should be disabled. But once the PO is approved and user wants to make any change in the approved PO, On selecting “Hold” checkbox option, this field should be active and user should then be allowed to set any value from the field list and save the Order. I tried the Automation steps but could not figure out how to achieve it.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the rowselected event of the POOrder, add your conditions and use the PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible to hide/show your field.

It will be something like below.

```
protected virtual void POOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del)
        {
            if (e.Row == null) return;
            if (del != null) del(sender, e);

  PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<YOUR custom FIELD>(sender, e.Row, <Your true condition to show>);
        }
```